# "On this subject" or "in this subject"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have a sentence like:

> Using both class-oriented and subject-oriented schemes enables us to compare the results with other methods in this subject.

I want to say that using two approaches I can compare my method with other methods of same topic.

I'm not sure whether it's correct or I should use `on this subject`.

I googled it and I found sentences with both of them.

Comment: There isn't enough context to make a determination. It could just as well be "of this subject" or "involving this subject". Could you provide more?

Comment: @BobRodes, thanks for the reply. I added text from the beginning of the paragraph. Your suggestions are also good, thanks.

Comment: Ok, that's better.  What methods are we talking about, and what subject are we talking about?

Comment: @BobRodes, it's an algorithm for cardiac arrhythmia classification. I'm using two approaches and I want to say that in this way I can compare my method with many  other methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither one works very well, which is why you are having difficulty. If you go [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+this+subject%2C+in+this+subject&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20this%20subject%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20this%20subject%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20this%20subject%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20this%20subject%3B%2Cc0), and click on the list of books up to 2000 for both *on* and *in* this subject, you will find a good number of examples of their usage.  Here is one example of each:

> I would appreciate any information on this subject.
>   Students should be immersed in this subject early.

I would go another way.  Something like this:

> Using both class-oriented and subject-oriented schemes enables us to compare the results with the other methods used for this type of classification.

Putting *the* in there establishes that you are contrasting your method with a set of existing methods that are also used to do the same thing.

Comment: +1 for the link to "Google Books Ngram Viewer". It's an extremely useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood *subject* stands for a person/human being, so, *in this subject*. If it stands for a topic, then *on this subject*, even prefer *of this subject*, however, you should modify your sentence with another word to avoid that ambiguities for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But by `subject` I mean `topic`. In `subject-oriented` it means patient but I want to say that I can compare my method with other methods in this topic.

Comment: "...in this area of research"? If I'm understanding the question correctly, using "subject" twice, differently, is problematic.

Comment: I agree with Doug.  Using subject in two different ways makes your statement harder to understand.